# Append string of text to lines containing another string of text in bourne and bash

Tags: regex, xcode, bash, awk, sed

I work with a load of developers that use the dreaded XCode on OSX!  More-so, they need to have many versions on their build agents and switch between them to build older code that is tightly coupled to said versions! (I know, not my choice!)  Anyhow, to try and get some sanity to the situation, on their builds I do a little report that shows

(a) what XCodes are under /Applications, using the command:

```
$ find /Applications -name Xcode\* -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

That gives output such as:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app
```

... and...
(b) Which Xcode the 'xcode-select' tool has set their system to use, with the command:

```
$ xcode-select -p | sed 's#/Contents/Developer##g'
```

( xcode-select gives output such as `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` or `/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app/Contents/Developer` depending which is in use )

Anyway, what I am hoping to do is tidy this report up a little.  I was hoping that instead of first outputting the set of folders that are on the system, then the one that is set to be used, that instead I could output just the list that is generated by find while appending an arrow, either `<--`, `<--Selected-Version--` or something like that, to the end of any lines that contain the string of text/match a given regex that is given.

Although just solving this would be great, as I always try to make generic code I can re-use, I was hoping to make a function that I can reuse in similar contexts if that doesn't make the whole idea unworkable.

My attempt at this is as follows:

```
appendArrowToMatchingLines ()
{
    local SEARCHstr
    local TEXT_BUFFERstr
    # Have we got more than one argument, but not exactly two
    if [ "$#" -gt "1" ] && [ "$#" -ne "2" ]
    then
        printf -v SEARCHstr "%q" "${1}"
        shift
        printf -v TEXT_BUFFERstr "%q" "$@"
        shift $#
    # Have we got exactly two arguments?
    elif [ "$#" -eq "2" ]
    then
        printf -v SEARCHstr "%q" "${1}"
        shift
        printf -v TEXT_BUFFERstr "%q" "${1}"
        shift
    # Third form, we must be streaming from STD_IN
    else
        printf -v SEARCHstr "%q" "${1}"
        printf -v TEXT_BUFFERstr "%q" "$( cat - )"
    fi
    printf "%s" "${TEXT_BUFFERstr}" | sed "/${SEARCHstr}/ s/$/<--/"
}
```

But, unfortunately this does not work :(  Any help with building an "append an arrow to matching lines" function would be greatly appreciated!

Another angle, and it would be even more ideal if I could do this without buffering, is I have seen something like:

```
$ find . -name test.txt -exec sed -i '/PATTERN/ s/)$/); /' '{}' \;
```

in forums where they suggest that they can do a similar thing in one stream, though I couldn't get that to work either, and I don't really know where to start with that! :)

Again, any help from someone who understands the world of sed/awk would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: There is no sed/awk. There is sed and there is awk. 2 completely separate tools with their own syntax, uses, etc. When you want to subsitute some text on a single line you use sed. When you want to do more than that you use awk. What you NEVER do is write a shell script to do bits of the job and call sed to do others. If you just post some clear sample input and expected output we can show you how to write a concise awk scrip to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will append the string supplied as the 2nd argument to lines matching the 1st argument:

```
# Append $2 to lines matching $1
function str_append() {
    [ $# -lt 2 ] && return 2
    local search=$1; local suffix=$2

    # Safely escape the $search variable for use in sed LHS (search pattern)
    search=$(printf -- '%s\n' "$search" | sed 's/[[\.*^$(){}?+|/]/\\&/g')   
    # escape special symbols '&', '/' and '\' in sed RHS (replacement)
    suffix=$(printf -- '%s\n' "$suffix" | sed 's/[\&/]/\\&/g')

    # Append $suffix to lines matching $search
    sed "/$search\+/s/$/${suffix}/"
}
```

Of course, in order to make this function available for command-line usage, you have to place it in a file which is loaded in your environment, like in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files. Then:

To add an arrow to all lines matching "file_pattern", run:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | str_append "file_pattern" " <--"
```

To add an arrow to all lines outputted by `find` run:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | str_append "." " <--"
```

The above function will output all lines, both those which match the search string and those which do not. In order to output only the matching lines and append an arrow to those, run:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | grep 'file_pattern' | str_append '.' ' <--'
```

or if you want this behaviour as the default, change the `sed` line to:

```
sed -n "/$search\+/s/$/${suffix}/p"
```

`-n` : do not print input lines by default
`/p` : print the line if we had a match

Comment: That is great, thank you very much!  Although, I can't actually get it to work :(  Replicating the output of the command I want to append arrows to using echo: `echo "/Applications/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app"` whilst appending `| str_append "." " <--"` as in your example or `| str_append "/Applications/Xcode.app" " <--"` or even `| str_append "\/Applications\/Xcode.app"` just don't seem to work :(  I am using OSX.  Do you have any special shell options turned on or off?

Comment: The input should consist of multiple lines, as in your `find` example. Your `echo` example outputs just one line, so it does not make sense to add an arrow to the whole line. You can use `printf` instead. E.g. 
`printf '%s\n%s' "/Applications/Xcode.app" "/Applications/Xcode6.1.1.app" | str_append "." "<--"` .       
I also edited the function and made it also work with strings containing slashes and other special symbols as a search string, so now your `| str_append "/Applications/Xcode.app" " <--"` should work. If it still doesn't work, please tell me if there are any error messages.

Comment: Also edited the function again, to remove "bash-isms". Now all variable escapes are made with sed. Please try with the new version and tell me if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To append text to a matching line is just:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c

$ awk '/b/{$0 = $0 " <--- here is b"} 1' file
a
b <--- here is b
c
```

If you need something else, edit your question to show clear, precise, testable sample input and expected output.

wrt your comment below:

```
$ awk -v var=" <--- here is b" '/b/{$0 = $0 var} 1' file
a
b <--- here is b
c

$ var=" <--- here is b"
$ awk -v var="$var" '/b/{$0 = $0 var} 1' file
a
b <--- here is b
c
```

Comment: That is amazing and I think pretty much exactly what I need, however, I am trying to slightly modify to allow the arrow string to be passed in as a variable, but I must be making some silly mistake as I can't get it to work :(  I have tried things allong the lines of both `awk -v VAR="${VAR}" '/b/{$0 = $0 VAR} 1'` and `awk '/b/{$0 = $0 "${VAR}"} 1'`, and even `awk '/b/{$0 = $0 '"${VAR}'"} 1'`, any idea what I am mucking up?

Comment: No, your first command should work just fine. Never attempt the other 2 - awk is not shell so you cannot use shell variables as variables in awk scripts and trying to expand shell vars to become part of the awk script itself creates all sorts of issues. I edited my answer to show 2 ways to do it.